# How would one concatenate one column from multiple rows and then insert that value into a single column of another row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So let's say we have this table:

```
    CAR_PARTS
    ID   CAR_ID  PART_NAME       
    1    11      Steering Wheel  
    2    22      Steering Wheel 
    3    22      Headlights
```

And we also have this table:

```
    CARS
    ID   CAR_MODEL        PART_NAME_LIST
    11   Mustang          
    22   Camaro           
    33   F-150
```

How do add data to the PART_NAME_LIST column like this:

```
    CARS
    ID   CAR_MODEL        PART_NAME_LIST
    11   Mustang          Steering Wheel
    22   Camaro           Steering Wheel, Headlights
    33   F-150            (No parts were found)
```

Comment: It will be the violation of the [1NF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: I agree, but the data is in really bad shape and there is a lot of it.  For example, a foreign key relationship between the two tables is not possible.  The only solution I see is to use this summary column model.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Try this for versions of SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2017:

```
declare @CAR_PARTS table(ID int, CAR_ID int, PART_NAME nvarchar(128));
insert @CAR_PARTS values
  (1, 11, 'Steering Wheel'),  
  (2, 22, 'Steering Wheel'), 
  (3, 22, 'Headlights');

declare @CARS table(
  ID int,
  CAR_MODEL nvarchar(30),
  PART_NAME_LIST nvarchar(max) null);

insert @CARS(ID, CAR_MODEL) values
  (11, 'Mustang'),
  (22, 'Camaro'),
  (33, 'F-150');

select
  c.ID,
  c.CAR_MODEL,
  stuff(cast((
    select
      ',' + cp.PART_NAME [text()]
    from @CAR_PARTS cp
    where cp.CAR_ID = c.ID
    for xml path('')
  )as nvarchar(max)), 1, 1, '') PART_NAME_LIST
from @CARS c;
```

In SQL Server 2017 it is possible to use the [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
select
  c.ID,
  c.CAR_MODEL,
  string_agg(cp.PART_NAME,',') PART_NAME_LIST
from @CARS c left join @CAR_PARTS cp
  on c.ID = cp.CAR_ID
group by c.ID, c.CAR_MODEL;
```

Check on this online [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f24682e1841b2e4a990a2c42addaabf).

**UPD**: possible UPDATE statements were added to the demo.